# How to break or continue Ext.each

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.each(boundsExtend, function(value)
{
    if(value != record.ID) break;
});
```

So how do I break or continue Ext.each loop?

Comment: Here is a similar exception I got when not doing this, and removing an object.  Therefore itemId was not there.  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemId' of undefined "

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-each):

> If the supplied function returns
>   false, iteration stops and this method
>   returns the current index.

So as in the OP's example (assuming `record` is in scope and non-null):

```
Ext.each(boundsExtend, function(value) {
  if (value != record.ID) {
    return false;
  }
  // other logic here if ids do match
});
```

Note that returning `false` exits the loop completely, so in this case the first non-matching record will bypass any additional checking.

However I'm guessing that what you're really trying to do is loop *until* you find the matching record, do some logic, then short-circuit the loop. If that's the case, the logic would actually be:

```
Ext.each(boundsExtend, function(value) {
  if (value === record.ID) {
    // do your match logic here...
    // if we're done, exit the loop:
    return false;
  }
  // no match, so keep looping (i.e. "continue")
});
```

Any other value that is not explicitly `false` (e.g. `null` by default) will keep the loop going.

Comment: Return anything but false.

Comment: continue is not working for me. Can you please help how can I do that

Answer (score 4):

```
var countries = ['Vietnam', 'Singapore', 'United States', 'Russia'];

Ext.Array.each(countries, function(name, index, countriesItSelf) {
    console.log(name);
});

Ext.Array.each(countries, function(name, index, countriesItSelf) {
if (name === 'Singapore') {
    return false; // break here
}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Return `false` to 'break' and return anything but `false` to 'continue'.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
Ext.each(array, function(ele){
    console.log(ele);
    if(ele !== 2){
        return false;  // break out of `each` 
    }
})

Ext.each(array, function(ele){
     console.log(ele);
    if(ele !== 3){
        return true; // continue
    }
})
```