# how to terminate a function in `Ext.each`?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to break or continue Ext.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491982/how-to-break-or-continue-ext-each)

exactly what i want to achieve is to check a string in an array,..
if the privilege is true, then return `true`...

```
var Data = {
    appPrivilege : [{
        module : "info",
        priv : true
    },{
        module : "about",
        priv : false
    }]
}

App = {
    AP : function(a){
        Ext.each(Data.appPrivilege, function(c){
            if (c.module == a && c.priv==true){
                console.info("here");
                //return true;
                return "a";
            }
        });
        return "b";
    }
}

console.info(App.AP("info"));
```

but in firebug it show `here` and `b`. how to terminate `Ext.each` ??

Comment: sorry i didn't find it while googling

Answer (score 0):

Ext and jQuery just wants the callback to return false

```
if (c.module == a && c.priv==true){
  console.info("here");
  return false;
}
```